# How to bypass install blocked notification from my app?

Tags: android, notifications, installation

I have created an android app and when i try to install it shows a notification in the image.
  - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GVBt.png)
I know how to install it. But when i give that to others they don't have to see the notification.
So to bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

They have to change their settings to allow non play store apps. There are plenty of articles you can point your users to that describe how to do it. For instance, here's one: http://support.frostwire.com/hc/en-us/articles/204106319-How-to-fix-Install-Blocked-error-while-installing-FrostWire-Plus-on-Android-